# Send Email when a column value changes in a google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on this [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W6RFjxjO1kNYijr2QSmSeVDyprCMh1Sn597z60wFfjY/edit#gid=0) and would like to do the following

1. Send an email when column G is edited
2. The email should inform the recipient that the cell changed from this value to the other e.g The Column G Cell G490 was modified from 'undefined' to 'August 2021'
3. The email should also highlight only the row that was affected and the column headers which are E3:H3

Below is an example of how the email body should look like

[image]

I'm using the following code but running into errors.

One of the error i'm getting is

"ReferenceError: rows is not defined"

I'm modifying the code from [this tutorial](https://spreadsheet.dev/send-email-when-google-sheet-is-edited)

```
function processEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var rows = sheet.getRangeByName("EmailChanges").getValues();
  var headerRow = rows.shift();
  var editedRow = e.range.getRow();

  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Template");
  template.headerRow = headerRow;
  template.editedRow = editedRow;
  
  
  var html = template.evaluate().getContent();
  if(row>=3 && row<=1339 && col>6 && col==7 && editedSheet.getName()=="Change Requests"){
    //Send email
  var message = "The Column G Cell "+editedCell.getA1Notation()+" was modified from '"+e.oldvalue+"' to '"+e.value+"'";
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: "example@gmail.com",
    subject: "Change",message,
    name:'GSD BI',
    htmlBody: html
  });
}
}
```

The Html code is

```
Please see the highlighted row below for information about the Changes.

<hr>
<br>
<table cellpadding='5'>
  <tr>
    <th bgcolor='#eaeaea'><?= headerRow[0] ?></th>
    <th bgcolor='#eaeaea'><?= headerRow[1] ?></th>
    <th bgcolor='#eaeaea'><?= headerRow[2] ?></th>
  </tr>
  <? var rowIndex = 3; ?>
  <? for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { ?>
  <?   var background = rowIndex === editedRow ? "#e06666" : "#ffffff";  ?>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor='<?= background ?>'><?= rows[i][0] ?></td>
    <td bgcolor='<?= background ?>'><?= rows[i][1] ?></td>
    <td bgcolor='<?= background ?>'><?= rows[i][2] ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?    rowIndex = rowIndex + 1; ?>
  <? } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: @NEWAZA I'm getting the error ReferenceError: rows is not defined

Comment: Ah, you should start by adding what sheet you're trying to pull these values from, `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();` just references the spreadsheet. Try: `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName(`NAME_OF_SHEET`)` and let me know

Comment: I'm now getting the error TypeError: sheet.getRangeByName is not a function
    at processEdit(Code:3:20)

Comment: Looks like the tutorial is really old, the method getRangeByName() doesn't exist anymore, you can try using instead [`getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/named-range#getrange)

Comment: The question doesn't include enough debugging details. How did you run the function? What is the original textual error message? Did you opened the project from the Google Sheets user interface or from other place? Have you signed in into multiple accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When the column "G" is manually edited, you want to run your script by the installable OnEdit trigger.
- When the script is run, you want to retrieve the edited row and create `message` and send them as an email.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `rows` is not defined. This is the reason for your issue of `"ReferenceError: rows is not defined"`. And also, `col` is not declared.
- When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, the name of the named range is `EmailChange`. But, you are using the name `EmailChanges`.
- `e.oldvalue` always returns `undefined`. The property name is `oldValue`.
- In your template, `rows` is not put.
- From your showing expected goal, `message` is not included in the template.
- `message` of `MailApp.sendEmail(message)` has no property of `message`.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

##### Google Apps Script: `Code.gs`

```js
function processEdit(e) {
  var { source, range, value, oldValue } = e;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var editedRow = range.rowStart;
  if (editedRow >= 3 && editedRow <= 1339 && range.columnStart == 7 && sheet.getSheetName() == "Change Requests") {
    var message = "The Column G Cell " + range.getA1Notation() + " was modified from '" + oldValue + "' to '" + value + "'";
    var namedRange = source.getRangeByName("EmailChange");
    var rows = namedRange.getValues();
    var headerRow = rows[0];
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("Template");
    var idx = editedRow - namedRange.getRow();
    template.message = message;
    template.rows = [rows[idx]];
    template.headerRow = headerRow;
    template.editedRow = editedRow;
    var html = template.evaluate().getContent();
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: "example@gmail.com",
      subject: "Change",
      name: 'GSD BI',
      htmlBody: html
    });
  }
}
```

##### HTML: `Template.html`

```html
<p><?!= message ?></p>
<p>Please see the highlighted row below for information about the Changes.</p>

<hr>
<br>
<table cellpadding='5'>
  <tr>
    <th bgcolor='#eaeaea'><?= headerRow[0] ?></th>
    <th bgcolor='#eaeaea'><?= headerRow[1] ?></th>
    <th bgcolor='#eaeaea'><?= headerRow[2] ?></th>
  </tr>
  <? var rowIndex = 3; ?>
  <? for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { ?>
  <?   var background = rowIndex === editedRow ? "#e06666" : "#ffffff";  ?>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor='<?= background ?>'><?= rows[i][0] ?></td>
    <td bgcolor='<?= background ?>'><?= rows[i][1] ?></td>
    <td bgcolor='<?= background ?>'><?= rows[i][2] ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?    rowIndex = rowIndex + 1; ?>
  <? } ?>
</table>
```

#### Note:

- In your script, `oldValue` is used. In this case, please edit the cell by directly and manually putting the value. When you copy and paste the value, `oldValue` is not returned. Please be careful about this.
- This modified script is for your sample Spreadsheet. If your actual Spreadsheet is different, please check the name of the named range again.
- In this script, from your showing script, it supposes that your script is run by the installed OnEdit trigger. If you directly run the script with the script editor, an error occurs because of no event object. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [sendEmail(message) of Class MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage)
- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)